# Why does Angular ask me for these properties, and how can I fix it?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

```
/* Services: client-service.ts */
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';  
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import { Client } from '../models/Client';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClientService {
  clientsCollection!: AngularFirestoreCollection<Client>;
  clientDoc!: AngularFirestoreDocument<Client>;
  clients!: Observable<Client>[];
  client!: Observable<Client>;

 
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.clientsCollection = this.afs.collection('clients', ref => ref.orderBy('lastName', 'asc'));
  }

  getClients(): Observable<Client[]> {
    // Get clients with the id
    this.clients = this.clientsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(action => {
        const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Client;
        data.id = action.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });
    return this.clients;
  }

}
```

**I am getting these two errors**:

- Type 'Observable<Client[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 24 more.
- Type 'Observable[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Client[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.

Here is the component that is subscribing to it:

```
/* the client-component.ts file */
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ClientService } from '../../services/client.service';
import { Client } from '../../models/Client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients',
  templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients.component.css']
})
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {
/* Properties */
clients!: Client[];

  constructor(private clientService: ClientService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(clients => this.clients = clients);
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What type does snapShotChanges return? If it is an observable you are mapping incorrectly when you should be subscribing.

Comment: yeah the code I shared above initially is the Service file.  I will update with the component that's subscribing to it.

Comment: I’ve provided a proposed solution based on your updates.

Comment: Placing this comment in both areas, so hope you see it:) 
For the second line I get this error: Type 'Observable<Client[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Client>[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more. I also get an additional error: ')' expected. For return this.clients; I'm getting this error: (same as before too) : Type 'Observable<Client>[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Client[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.

Comment: I have also updated the original question with a exact screenshot of my initial error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a map on an observable type. This needs to look something like this instead:

```
getClients(): Observable<Client[]> {
this.clients = this.clientsCollection.snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(
      map(c => {
        return c.map(a => {
          let data = a.payload.doc.data() as Client;
          data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
        });
    });
  return this.clients;
  }
```

Comment: For the second line I get this error: Type 'Observable<Client[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Client>[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.

I also get an additional error:  ')' expected.

For return this.clients; I'm getting this error:  (same as before too) :  Type 'Observable<Client>[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Client[]>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.

Comment: clients!: Observable<Client[]>; instead of what you have for the declaration

Comment: OH MY GOD!  Ha ha I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you so much man!

Comment: Hey!  Sorry to bother again, but I'm getting a new error in my command line:
 node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:219:25 - error TS2694: Namespace
....... my file path.. node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

237     static ɵinj: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<ApplicationModule>;

Comment: I would open a new question. If you want you can give me the new link as a comment. I would start though by removing your node modules directory, running `npm clear cache --force` and `npm i`

Comment: Thank you!  After follwing those steps and still getting the errors in the command line, I posted the question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68443084/what-do-these-angularcli-errors-mean-when-theres-no-problems-detected-in-vsc