# What do these AngularCli errors mean, when there's no "problems" detected in VsCode?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase, npm

Firstly, this is a follow up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68424668/why-does-angular-ask-me-for-these-properties-and-how-can-i-fix-it/68425754?noredirect=1#comment120958212_68425754):

and.... secondly, I am only getting these errors in the Terminal btw.  I'm not that new to Angular but very new to FireStore, and Firebase :)

I have created an account with Firebase for the first time, and I think I copied over all the api stuff correctly, and when I look in VsCode, no problems show up.  However, I was wondering why nothing was showing up in localhost right... so I look into my terminal, the command line, and these are some errors that are showing up.

Heres some steps I took:

- Deleted node modules
- npm cache clean --force
- npm install

but then I'm still getting the same errors!

```
Build at: 2021-07-19T15:14:31.757Z - Hash: 1d1a58a540ce70023842 - Time: 20427ms

Warning: D:\WEBSITES\Projects\clientpanel\node_modules\angularfire2\node_modules\@angular\fire\__ivy_ngcc__\es2015\firebase.app.module.js depends on 'firebase/app'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: D:\WEBSITES\Projects\clientpanel\node_modules\firebase\firestore\dist\index.esm.js depends on '@firebase/firestore'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: D:\WEBSITES\Projects\clientpanel\src\app\app.module.ts depends on 'angularfire2'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: D:\WEBSITES\Projects\clientpanel\src\app\app.module.ts depends on 'angularfire2/auth'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Warning: D:\WEBSITES\Projects\clientpanel\src\app\app.module.ts depends on 'angularfire2/firestore'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies



Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:219:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

219     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ApplicationInitStatus, [{ optional: true; }]>;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:220:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

220     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<ApplicationInitStatus>;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:750:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

750     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<Compiler>;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5066:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

5066     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<PlatformRef, never>;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:5067:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

5067     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<PlatformRef>;
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6454:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

6454     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<SystemJsNgModuleLoader, [null, { optional: true; }]>;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6455:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

6455     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<SystemJsNgModuleLoader>;
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6651:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

6651     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<Testability, never>;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6652:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

6652     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<Testability>;
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:6696:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

6696     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<TestabilityRegistry, never>;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:9639:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

9639     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<ɵConsole, never>;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts:9640:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/r3_symbols"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

9640     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<ɵConsole>;
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts:13:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

13     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFireAuth, [null, { optional: true; }, null, null]>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.d.ts:14:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

14     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<AngularFireAuth>;
  m                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.module.d.ts:4:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

4     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFireAuthModule, never>;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.module.d.ts:5:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

5     static ɵmod: ɵngcc0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<AngularFireAuthModule, never, never, never>;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.module.d.ts:6:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

6     static ɵinj: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<AngularFireAuthModule>;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:48:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

48     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFireModule, never>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: [0mnode_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:49:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

49     static ɵmod: ɵngcc0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<AngularFireModule, never, never, never>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/firebase.app.module.d.ts:50:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

50     static ɵinj: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<AngularFireModule>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.d.ts:30:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

30     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFirestore, [null, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, { optional: true; }, null, null, { optional: true; }]>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.d.ts:31:26 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

31     static ɵprov: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<AngularFirestore>;
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


0mError: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.module.d.ts:7:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

7     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<AngularFirestoreModule, never>;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.module.d.ts:8:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

8     static ɵmod: ɵngcc0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<AngularFirestoreModule, never, never, never>;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.module.d.ts:9:25 - error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/WEBSITES/Projects/clientpanel/node_modules/angularfire2/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

9     static ɵinj: ɵngcc0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<AngularFirestoreModule>;
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you installed an angular library that is no longer in use - angularfire2 is now just @angular/fire

try this from the terminal window or command window

```
npm uninstall angularfire2
npm uninstall @angular/fire
npm uninstall firebase
```

in your module where you are importing angular fire make sure you remove any references to it.
then type

```
ng add @angular/fire 
npm install 
npm install firebase
```

Comment: Thank you, so much!!